# Regex multiple matches for HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I want to match multiple `data-i18n` attributes with a JavaScript regexp.

I tried the following regexp :

```
var regexp = /(data\-i18n="[^"]+")/g;
```

which in my head seemed rather straight forward, but it ended up not working.

If you try to match on the following HTML tag :

```
<a random-attr="ok" data-i18n="first match" data-i18n="second match">my text</a>
```

doing an exec like this :

```
/(data\-i18n="[^"]+")/g.exec('<a random-attr="ok" data-i18n="first match" data-i18n="second match">my text</a>')
```

will raise the following issue :

- There are two matches, but they are actually duplicate matches.

The result is :

```
[ 'data-i18n="first match"',
  'data-i18n="first match"',
  index: 20,
  input: '<a random-attr="ok" data-i18n="first match" data-i18n="second match">my text</a>' ]
```

- Any ideas on how to have multiple matches for my attribute ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Oh God no, guess it's time for [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('data-i18n')`

Comment: And you can't have two attributes with the same name.

Comment: I'm not client-side, so no selectors. And I'm not trying to program a tokenizer for HTML just matching one specific tag which shouldn't be very complicated.

Comment: You can't have two attributes with the same name, but you could for example have two tags with the same attribute, which would be the exact same situation.

Comment: And then you would have an issue as you're working with strings, and that's why you need a proper DOM parser, not regex. If you're not clientside, where are you, and why isn't the question properly tagged

Comment: Node.js, but I thought that since it wasn't using Node.js specific libraries it wouldn't be too useful but I will retag the question.

Comment: The regex you have seems to work for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/GjPUH/

Comment: Hum thanks. For some reason, `exec()` didn't return the right results ...

Comment: With `exec` you have to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with your regex; its with how you're expecting `exec` to behave.  The return value of `exec` has the full match at position 0, and then the match of each capture group following that.  Since you wrapped the whole regex in a capturing group, you're seeing the same string at positions 0 and 1 of the array.

The right way to use a global regex with `exec` is to keep calling `exec` until it returns `null`; it will return the next match each time.  However, if you use `String.match(Regexp)`, it will return what you expect - an array containing all of the matches.